# rewriting a SQL/vb6 app - should I use nHibernate or Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate, orm

I have a legacy VB6 app which I am rewriting in .Net. I have not used an ORM package before (being the old fashioned type who likes to know what SQL is being used), but I have seen good reports of NNibernate and I am tempted to use it for this project. I just want to check I won't be shooting myself in the foot.

Because my new app will initially run alongside the existing one, any ORM I use must work with the existing database schema. Also, I need to use SQL server text searching. From what I gather, LINQ to SQL does not support Text searching, so this will rule it out.

The app uses it's own method of allocating IDs for new objects - will NHibernate allow this or does it expect to use it's own mechanisms?

Also I have read that NHibernate does caching. I need to make sure that rows inserted outside of NHibernate are immediately accessible when accessing the database from NHibernate and vice versa.

There are 4 or 5 main tables and 10 or so subsidiary tables. although a couple of the main tables have up to a million rows, the app itself will normally be only returning a few. The user load is low so I don't anticipate performance being a problem.

At the moment I'm not sure whether it will be ASP.NET or win forms but either way I will be expecting to use data binding.

In terms of functionality, The app is not particulatly complicated - the budget to re-implement it is about 20 man days, so if I am going to use ORM it has to be something that will start paying for itself pretty quickly. Similarly I want the app to be simple to deploy and not require some monster enterprise framework.

Any thoughts on whether this is a suitable project for NHibernate would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

While ORMs are good, I personally wouldn't take on the risk of trying to use any ORM on a 20 day project if I had to absorb the ORM learning curve as I went.

If you have ADO.NET infrastructure you are comfortable with and you can live without ORM features, that is the much less risky approach to take.

You should learn ORMs and Linq (not necessarily Linq To Sql) eventually, but it's much more enjoyable when there is no immediate time pressure.

This sounds more like a risk management issue and that requires you to make a personal decision about how willing you are to see the project fail due to embracing new (to you) technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully fitted an NHibernate domain model to a few legacy database schemas - it's not yet proved impossible, but it is sometimes not without its difficulties. The easiest schemas to map are those where all primary keys and foreign keys are single column ones, but with so few tables you should be able to do the mapping relatively quickly even if this is not true of yours.

I strongly recommend, particularly given your timescale, that you use Fluent NHibernate to do your mappings - the time to learn the XML mapping file syntax may be too big an ask. However, you will need to use an XML mapping file for your full-text indexing stuff (assuming that's what you meant), writing these as named SQL queries. (See [nhibernate.info documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html) for details.)

Suggest you spend a day or two trying to create a model for a couple of your tables, and writing code to interact with them. There'll always be people on SO ready to answer any questions you have.

You may also want to take a look at Linq to NHibernate - we've found it helpful in terms of abstracting even more of our database access stuff away behind a simple interface. But it's Fluent NHibernate that will give you the biggest and quickest win in terms of "cheating" on the NHibernate learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out LLBL Gen Pro. It is a very mature ORM that handles a lot of different scenarios.